# Wordpress - Prevent redirection to main URL

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I tried to copy the files of a WordPress website on another domain of mine.
But it keeps redirecting to the old domain name.. I'm not a WordPress expert and it's also not my website - that's why I don't have a GUI and only the files.

How and where can I disable the redirection to the main domain in the files? I can't seem to find it.

Thanks for the efforts.

> **For example**:
>
> WordPress website "test.com" copy paste --> "testtest.com"
>
> "testtest.com" redirects to --> "test.com" when entered in URL

Comment: You need to edit the database and change the `homeurl` and `siteurl` to the new domain. Once you've done that, go to `Settings` > `Permalinks` and click save in order to update your `.htaccess` file as well.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this only with the files and without the GUI of wordpress? I don't have the login because it's not my website. @APAD1

Comment: You can [override the siteurl and homeurl in the wp-config.php file](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/change-wordpress-url/). Check option 2 from the link.

Comment: Hmm.. I do have access on the database. The thing is that I can't change the database content because the site is online and i have to test it on another domain.. It would fail if i change anything in the database. @APAD1

Comment: Check my updated comment, you can override the database values in the `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue! Could you make an answer so i can accept it for future readers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you transfer a Wordpress install to a new domain, there are 2 values you need to update in your database. One is the `homeurl` and the other is the `siteurl`. Typically these changes would be made directly in the database, either by modifying the sql file before importing it on the new server or by accessing the database using PHPMyAdmin or some other form of database management software. However, in the event that you don't have access to the database or do not want to make the change in the database, you can also override the settings in your `wp-config.php` file using the following options:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourdomain.com');
```