# ports mapping in nginx docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose, port

I'm not sure what I don't understand, so it's hard to ask the right question :

I configured 3 docker images to create container for a local wordpress, using docker compose with nginx, mariadb, and wordpress.

for the nginx container I map the ports like that :

**docker-compose.yml :**

```
services:
  nginx:
    ports:
      - 443:443
```

1. If I don't map any ports in the docker-compose.yml file, the localhost website is not accessible with url `https://localhost`, but I can find the ip address with this command `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' nginx_container` (that I don't really understant), and the if I try to access the website at the ip, ie. "https://192.168.160.4/" it will parially work : the wordpress page will show with missing styles, and the network panel in dev tools reveals that lots of request didn't worked, like the styles .css
2. If I map to "443", without specifying host port, I get the same result.
3. If I map 443:443 in the nginx container, the website works, with `https://localhost`.
4. If now I map 3002:443 for example, I can't access the website at `https://localhost:3002`, but it's different than situation (1), I can see a redirection happening

**Case 3**, I think I understand, I tell the nginx container, the only one that need to be connected to the outside of the container network, to listen to host port 443, and maps it to internal network at port 443, default for https, so everything goes smooth

**Case 1 and 2** I don't understand why it works only partially ? I thought docker allocate a host port, once I find it I can use it to access nginx, and now from inside the container network everything should work as if I was trying to connect to port 443 ?

**and case 4**, the one I'm really interested in, I have no idea why it doesn't work, I thought that docker would do some kind of transformation : everything in host that request port 3002 will be translated in the container network as port 443, but clearly not. I would think that, at least, it would work like in case 1 and 2, but still not.

Since I'm not sure what is relevant here, I don't want to add unnecessary content, but I should add that I didn't use the existing docker images, I created my own.

Comment: The redirect probably comes from Wordpress' `WP_SITEURL` configuration. See [Wordpress - Prevent redirection to main URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56344567/283366)

Comment: If you don't specify a host port, Docker will dynamically provision one. You can see which via `docker ps`. Specifying no ports will not expose your service to the host. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#ports

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure : I tried to change the value in the database to add :3002, I also tried to change it at the creation of wordpress, but both didn't worked. Actually, I would be more confused if it had work : wordpress is inside the container network, it shouldn't be affected by the port in th url I provide, or does it ? I thought only nginx was in "contact" with the host

Comment: as for the dynamically provided port, I understand that, that's my case 1 and 2, what I find weird in these cases is that it only partially works, the request for css files, but not only them, are failing. Instead, when I provide the "complete" mapping 443:443 everything works just fine.

Comment: Wordpress tries to redirect to its _home_ URL all the time. Your CSS is probably failing to load because it too is using the `WP_SITEURL` as a prefix for assets

Comment: So, to be sure, you are saying I should change the value of 'WP_HOME' and 'WP_SITEURL' from "https://localhost" to "https://localhost:3002", right ? I did that and it changed nothing unfortunately. I don't understand how wordpress HOME url would know that I was asking for port 3002, I thought docker would kind of transform my request from port 3002 to port 443 ?

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address only works on a native-Linux system; it only directly using the Docker engine and not a VM-based solution like Docker Desktop; it only works from the same host; and the IP address can change as the container is routinely destroyed and recreated.  I wouldn't ever look up this IP address, and I wouldn't worry about application behavior if you happen to use it.

Comment: @Phil I didn't have time those last days to try again, finally you proposal was the right one, but I had other mechanism that prevented it to work properly, mainly the web browser cache, anyway now it's solved, thx. So i was wrong in my understanding of docker network.